# How to persist data in an array even when the page reloads, using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created a register and a login form using html and javascript. Where I am storing the user data in an array and then in local storage. For this I have initially declared an empty array called var users=[]; 
Thus, when the page reloads the previously stored data is lost as array becomes empty again and data in the local storage is overwritten. Please help, on how to avoid the array become empty after reloading the page.

Following is my controller.js-

```
//Declaring an empty array
var users = [];

//Setting id for each users
var idInput = makeCounter();

//Fetching data from textboxes in register.html
var firstnameInput  = document.getElementById("firstname");
var lastnameInput   = document.getElementById("lastname");
var emailInput      = document.getElementById("email");
var usernameInput   = document.getElementById("username");
var passwordInput   = document.getElementById("password");
var dobInput        = document.getElementById("dob");
var messageBox      = document.getElementById("editeddata");

//Declaring custom constructor function
function userdetails(id, firstname, lastname, email, dob, username, password){
    this.id         = id;
    this.firstname  = firstname;
    this.lastname   = lastname;
    this.email      = email;
    this.dob        = dob;
    this.username   = username;
    this.password   = password;
    this.FullName   = this.firstname +' ' + this.lastname;
}

//counter funtion, to fetch user id
function makeCounter() {
    var arraylength=users.length;
    return function(){
        return arraylength+1;
    }
}

//insert data while registration
function registerUser()
{
    //Email validation
    var emailinput = document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if(!(emailinput).match(emailReg) || emailinput=="")
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;

    }
    //check, if fields are empty
    if(firstnameInput.value=="" || lastnameInput.value=="" || passwordInput.value=="" || dobInput.value=="")
    {
        alert("Fields cannot be empty");
        return false;
    }

    //check, if a user already exist
    var usernameinput = document.forms["myform"]["username"].value;
    var passwordinput = document.forms["myform"]["password"].value;
    var ulen= users.length;
    for(i=0; i < ulen; i++)
    {
        if ( usernameinput == users[i].username && passwordinput == users[i].password)
        {
            alert("User already exists");
            return false;
        }
    }

    var user=new userdetails(idInput(),firstnameInput.value, lastnameInput.value, emailInput.value, dobInput.value, usernameInput.value, passwordInput.value);
    users.push(user);
    alert("Registered successfully");
    localStorage.setItem("key_users", JSON.stringify(users));

}
```

Comment: You just need to check for the existence of the data in your localStorage. If it's undefined, then create it as an empty array and do exactly what you are doing now. But if it exists already, then use that data and do not create an empty array.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohit..It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage value at the time of initialisation.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.key_users) {
    users = localStorage.key_users;
  } else {
    users = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this to check if the key is already in localStorage or not.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body onload="test()">


    <script>
    function test(){
        var value = (localStorage.getItem("key1"))
        console.log(value)
       if(value == null){
           localStorage.setItem("key1","value1")
           alert("Hellow")
       }else{
           var value=localStorage.getItem("key1");
           alert(value)
       }

    }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```